# JTable Left and Upper Lines are invisible

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I am trying to show some data on the JTables:

```
private JTable table1 = new JTable() {
    
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }

};

private JScrollPane secTabFirst() {

    Object [][] data = {{"90"},{"1700"},{"60"},{"0.7"}, {"Globular"}, {"Sinusoidal"}};
    
    String[] columnNames = {"Parameters"};
    
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    
    table1.setModel(model);
    
    table1.setTableHeader(null);
    table1.setShowHorizontalLines(true);
    table1.setShowVerticalLines(true);
    //table1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,240));
    //table1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(150,240));
    
    
    JScrollPane tb1 = new JScrollPane(table1);
    
    tb1.setVisible(true);
    
    return tb1;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
 
 JPanel panel = new JPanel();

 panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

 panel.add(secTabFirst());

}
```

The JTables are shown like these:
[image: The JTables are shown like these]

But the upper and left lines of the table are invisible. Also, it displays 2 dark-boxes after placing the tables in JScrollPane.

How can I make the lines visible and the dark-boxes disappear?

Thanks,

MB

Comment: Never set sizes or preferred sizes as you're doing

Comment: I have removed the lines that set sizes but the left and upper lines are still invisible and also the dark boxes got bigger: https://imgur.com/a/qIPWY2n

Comment: Create and post your most recent code as a decent [mre] for best chances of decent help. The link will explain what this is, how to create it, and how it can help you. It's not your entire program nor unrunnable snippets.

Comment: `table1.setTableHeader(null);` - If you don't want the table header displayed, then don't use a JTable. Instead use a `JList`. The API to add data to a `JList` is simplier since you don't need a 2D Array. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for a working example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to replicate your issue without any success, a `JTable` will never show the top and left borders by default, but this is not an issue as its usually expected to be rendered inside a `JScrollPane`. As @HovercraftFullOfEels mentioned try giving us an [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

[image]

```
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestApp {

    public TestApp() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(TestApp::new);
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        JTable table = new JTable() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        };

        Object[][] data = {{"90"}, {"1700"}, {"60"}, {"0.7"}, {"Globular"}, {"Sinusoidal"}};
        String[] columnNames = {"Parameters"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        table.setModel(model);
        table.setTableHeader(null);

        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table); // borders for top and left will be rendered thanks to JScrollPanes borders
        panel.add(pane);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**Update:**

You can however set a `Border` yourself which will ensure the top and left border lines are drawn:

```
table.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY, 1));
```

Which produces (`JTable` is not in a `JScrollPane` in the below screenshot to show the borders without interference):

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks all for the help guys. "setBorder" did the trick for me. Also, I have removed the "setSize" lines as @Hovercraft Full Of Eels suggested. I will make sure the code I post will be compliable and simple next time.

Comment: Glad to hear it mate

Answer (score 1):

I have a different solution which seems to work for me,
I have decided to keep the code simple (I have included all the code in a constructor):

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI {
  conn conn = new conn();
    // frame
    JFrame f;
    // Table
    JTable j;

    // Constructor
    GUI()
    {
        // Frame initiallization
        f = new JFrame();

        // Frame Title
        f.setTitle("JTable Example");

        // Data to be displayed in the JTable
        String[][] data = {
                { "data", "data", "data" },
                { "data", "data", "data" }
        };

        // Column Names
        String[] columnNames = { "data", "data", "data" };

        // Initializing the JTable
        j = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        j.setBounds(30, 40, 200, 300);

        // adding it to JScrollPane
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(j);
        f.add(sp);
        // Frame Size
        f.setSize(500, 200);
        // Frame Visible = true
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    // Main
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new GUI();
    }
}
```

here is the output:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/itzwX8KXwNKbZsjT8

please reply to this answer if there is any problem